# C# Element from XML Not Getting Bound To Class

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have below XML -

[My XML](https://pastebin.com/bUi5JrfD)

class structure ->

```
public class AvailabilityResponse
  {
    public string property_id { get; set; }
    public List<AvailRoom> rooms { get; set; }
    public Links links { get; set; }
    public int score { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
  }
public class AvailRoom
  {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string room_name { get; set; }
    public List<AvailRate> rates { get; set; }
  }
[Serializable]
  public class AvailRate
  {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int available_rooms { get; set; }
    public bool refundable { get; set; }
    public bool fenced_deal { get; set; }
    public bool fenced_deal_available { get; set; }
    public bool deposit_required { get; set; }
    public string merchant_of_record { get; set; }
    public List<Amenity> amenities { get; set; }
    public Links links { get; set; }
    //[XmlElement(ElementName = "bed_groups")]
    //public List<BedGroups> bed_groups { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "bed_groups")]
    public List<BedGroup> bed_groups { get; set; }
    public List<CancelPenalty> cancel_penalties { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, occupancy_pricing> occupancy_pricing { get; set; }
    public occupancy_pricing Occupancy { get; set; }
  }
public class BedGroup
  {
    public Links links { get; set; }
    public List<Configuration> configuration { get; set; }
  }
[Serializable]
  public class Links
  {

    public PaymentOptions payment_options { get; set; }

    public Book book { get; set; }

    public PriceCheck price_check { get; set; }

    public AdditionalRates additional_rates { get; set; }

    public Retrieve retrieve { get; set; }

    public Cancel cancel { get; set; }

    public Change change { get; set; }

    public string method { get; set; }

    public string href { get; set; }

  }
[Serializable]
  public class PriceCheck
  {
    public string method { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
  }
```

Problem with the structure is that , all the other elements are getting bound except bed_groups.

I tried with different conditions like serializing xml classes with visual studio , annoting them with different tags. But this did not worked.

Eg. cancel_penalties is having similar strucure , but it gets bound to c# class properly.
bed_groups does not gets bound. Every time it is null although value is present in xml.

Is it due to - `<a:item xmlns:a="item" item="37316" type="object">` in bed_groups and with other tags it only has - `<item type="object">` ?

What could be solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need the namespaces.  Code below is a subset of your classes and is tested and works

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serizlizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AvailabilityResponse));
            AvailabilityResponse response = (AvailabilityResponse)serizlizer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    public class AvailabilityResponse
    {
        [XmlArray("item")]
        [XmlArrayItem("rooms")]
        public List<AvailRoom> rooms { get; set; }
    }
    public class AvailRoom
    {
        public Item item { get; set; }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string room_name { get; set; }
        [XmlArray("rates")]
        [XmlArrayItem("item")]
        public List<AvailRate> rates { get; set; }
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class AvailRate
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "bed_groups")]
        public List<BedGroup> bed_groups { get; set; }
    }
    public class BedGroup
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "item", Namespace = "item")]
        public BedGroupItem item { get; set; }
    }
    public class BedGroupItem
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
        public Links links { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
        public List<Configuration> configuration { get; set; }
    }
    public class Links
    {
    }
    public class Configuration
    {
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use The below-described class structure.
`

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
[XmlRoot(ElementName="property_id")]
public class Property_id {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="id")]
public class Id {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="room_name")]
public class Room_name {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="status")]
public class Status {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="available_rooms")]
public class Available_rooms {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="refundable")]
public class Refundable {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="member_deal_available")]
public class Member_deal_available {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="package")]
public class Package {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="member")]
public class Member {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="corporate")]
public class Corporate {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="distribution")]
public class Distribution {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="sale_scenario")]
public class Sale_scenario {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="package")]
    public Package Package { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="member")]
    public Member Member { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="corporate")]
    public Corporate Corporate { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="distribution")]
    public Distribution Distribution { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="deposit_required")]
public class Deposit_required {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="merchant_of_record")]
public class Merchant_of_record {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="name")]
public class Name {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="item", Namespace="item")]
public class Item {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="id")]
    public Id Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="name")]
    public Name Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="a", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string A { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="item")]
    public string _item { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="description")]
    public Description Description { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="links")]
    public Links Links { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="configuration")]
    public Configuration Configuration { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="nightly")]
    public Nightly Nightly { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="totals")]
    public Totals Totals { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="amenities")]
public class Amenities {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="item", Namespace="item")]
    public List<Item> Item { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="method")]
public class Method {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="href")]
public class Href {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="payment_options")]
public class Payment_options {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="method")]
    public Method Method { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="href")]
    public Href Href { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="links")]
public class Links {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="payment_options")]
    public Payment_options Payment_options { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="price_check")]
    public Price_check Price_check { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="additional_rates")]
    public Additional_rates Additional_rates { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="recommendations")]
    public Recommendations Recommendations { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="description")]
public class Description {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="price_check")]
public class Price_check {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="method")]
    public Method Method { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="href")]
    public Href Href { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="type")]
public class Type {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string _type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="size")]
public class Size {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="quantity")]
public class Quantity {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="item")]
public class Item2 {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="type")]
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string _Type { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="size")]
    public Size Size { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="quantity")]
    public Quantity Quantity { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="item")]
    public List<Item2> Item2 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="id")]
    public Id Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="status")]
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="available_rooms")]
    public Available_rooms Available_rooms { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="refundable")]
    public Refundable Refundable { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="member_deal_available")]
    public Member_deal_available Member_deal_available { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="sale_scenario")]
    public Sale_scenario Sale_scenario { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="deposit_required")]
    public Deposit_required Deposit_required { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="merchant_of_record")]
    public Merchant_of_record Merchant_of_record { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="amenities")]
    public Amenities Amenities { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="links")]
    public Links Links { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="bed_groups")]
    public Bed_groups Bed_groups { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="occupancy_pricing")]
    public Occupancy_pricing Occupancy_pricing { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="promotions")]
    public Promotions Promotions { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="room_name")]
    public Room_name Room_name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="rates")]
    public Rates Rates { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="configuration")]
public class Configuration {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="item")]
    public Item2 Item2 { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="bed_groups")]
public class Bed_groups {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="item", Namespace="item")]
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="value")]
public class Value {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="currency")]
public class Currency {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="nightly")]
public class Nightly {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="item")]
    public Item2 Item2 { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="request_currency")]
public class Request_currency {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="value")]
    public Value Value { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="currency")]
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="billable_currency")]
public class Billable_currency {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="value")]
    public Value Value { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="currency")]
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="gross_profit")]
public class Gross_profit {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="request_currency")]
    public Request_currency Request_currency { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="billable_currency")]
    public Billable_currency Billable_currency { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="inclusive")]
public class Inclusive {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="request_currency")]
    public Request_currency Request_currency { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="billable_currency")]
    public Billable_currency Billable_currency { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="exclusive")]
public class Exclusive {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="request_currency")]
    public Request_currency Request_currency { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="billable_currency")]
    public Billable_currency Billable_currency { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="strikethrough")]
public class Strikethrough {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="request_currency")]
    public Request_currency Request_currency { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="billable_currency")]
    public Billable_currency Billable_currency { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="marketing_fee")]
public class Marketing_fee {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="request_currency")]
    public Request_currency Request_currency { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="billable_currency")]
    public Billable_currency Billable_currency { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="totals")]
public class Totals {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="gross_profit")]
    public Gross_profit Gross_profit { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="inclusive")]
    public Inclusive Inclusive { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="exclusive")]
    public Exclusive Exclusive { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="strikethrough")]
    public Strikethrough Strikethrough { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="marketing_fee")]
    public Marketing_fee Marketing_fee { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="occupancy_pricing")]
public class Occupancy_pricing {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="item", Namespace="item")]
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="deal")]
public class Deal {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="id")]
    public Id Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="description")]
    public Description Description { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="promotions")]
public class Promotions {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="deal")]
    public Deal Deal { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="rates")]
public class Rates {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="item")]
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="item")]
    public Item2 Item2 { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="rooms")]
public class Rooms {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="item")]
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="item")]
    public List<Item2> Item2 { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="additional_rates")]
public class Additional_rates {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="method")]
    public Method Method { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="href")]
    public Href Href { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="recommendations")]
public class Recommendations {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="method")]
    public Method Method { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="href")]
    public Href Href { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="score")]
public class Score {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="AvailabilityResponse")]
public class AvailabilityResponse {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="item")]
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}`
```

You can paste your XML at [XMLTOC#](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) to convert any XML to c# class

Comment: I have tried this. Why cancel_penalties  in my class structure is working fine and not bed_groups ?